# SQL Trigger chaining IF statements

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I seem to be unable to have multiple, non-related if statements in SQL

I have a table of users with a bunch of columns that should be unique, but some are also optional. Since SQL throws an error when more than one fields have a NULL value, I decided to approach the problem with a trigger.

Here is how I wrote it:

```
create definer = root@localhost trigger `check-if-unique-update`
    before UPDATE
    on contact
    for each row
    if new.phone2 is null
    then
        if (select count(id) from contact where phone2 = new.phone2 or phone = new.phone2) > 0
        then
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is something wrong with the Contact data you entered!';
        end if;
    end if;

    if new.email2 is not null
        then
        if (select count(id) from contact where email2 = new.email2 or email = new.email2)
            then
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is something wrong with the Contact data you entered!';
        end if;
    end if;

    if new.fax is not null
        then

        end if;
    end if;
```

First off, DataGrip (DataBase management IDE by JetBrains) gives me an error. When I then upload the file to the MySql DataBase it only shows the first if Statement

```
if new.phone2 is null
    then
        if (select count(id) from contact where phone2 = new.phone2 or phone = new.phone2) > 0
        then
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is something wrong with the Contact data you entered!';
        end if;
    end if;
```

I feel like I am missing some rudimentary detail, or is this just not possible in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried including a begin-end in your trigger?

```
create definer = root@localhost trigger `check-if-unique-update`
    before UPDATE
    on contact
    for each row
    begin
        if new.phone2 is null
        then
            if (select count(id) from contact where phone2 = new.phone2 or phone = new.phone2) > 0
            then
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is something wrong with the Contact data you entered!';
            end if;
        end if;

        if new.email2 is not null
            then
            if (select count(id) from contact where email2 = new.email2 or email = new.email2)
                then
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'There is something wrong with the Contact data you entered!';
            end if;
        end if;

        if new.fax is not null
            then

            end if;
        end if;
    end
```

Depending on your IDE, you may need to change the delimiter to `//` for example.

For reference see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html